# Can you make a changeable href and instead of a button have just a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, href

I am making a search engine and I would like to know if you can make a changeable `href` and instead of a `button` have just a `textbox`.
Here is what I have:
so can I use a different way that let's me just be able to hit enter instead let me know please

```html
<input id="input" type="url"></input>
<button id="link button"><a id="link" style="text-decoration: none; color: inherit;" href="" TARGET="_BLANK">enter</a></button>
<script src="script.js">
    var linkButton = document.getElementById("link button")
    linkButton.onclick = function(){
        var input = document.getElementById("input").value
        document.getElementById("link").setAttribute("href", "http://"+input)
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You want to redirect someone when he types something ? You need to be a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, I hope it resolves the issue:
Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/wh3jefz2/2/

```
document.getElementById('input').onkeypress = function(e){
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13'){

var input = document.getElementById("input").value

        window.open("http://"+input);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You have a check in your code for event being a `falsy` value. If so you assign `window.event` to the `e`. What is the case when the `onkeypress` event is `falsy`? And by the way, both: [keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which) are deprecated!

Comment: ```onkeypress``` event will keep the track of every key that has been pressed and only invoke when the enter key ie key 13 is pressed. :)

Comment: I mean when this condition: `if (!e)` is `true`?

Comment: When the browser is being controlled by any High Level api tools like chrome in headless mode.

Comment: Don't get it. What's the difference when it's in headless mode? For example, in puppeteer you do something like this: `await page.type('#input', String.fromCharCode(13));` API docs: [page.type](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.3.1&show=api-pagetypeselector-text-options) - it should fire events properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use a form

```js
function myfunction(){
var inputbox = document.getElementById('inputval');
 document.querySelector('#check').innerText = inputbox.value;
 window.open('http://'+inputbox.value);

}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="myfunction();return false;">
  <input name="value" id="inputval"/>
  <p id="check"></p>
</form>
```